# Can't Install Umbrel on my Ubuntu Mate 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, mate-desktop

I'm having a lot of problems when i run curl -L https://umbrel.sh | bash

```
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517

Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853
Err:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9

W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with your package manager.
You seem to have modified your apt sources?
Try running

sudo apt update

- if the issue persists follow https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_and_add_a_key
- or https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: that's off the mark. The repositories are for debian buster, and the asker says they're running Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

You're using debian repo sources on Ubuntu – that can't work, they are not compatible.

So, remove all lines that have been added that contain "debian" in /etc/apt/sources.list file and any files containing "debian" in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

Then, you *really*, *really* shouldn't do things like `curl ${url} | bash`. I've yet to see one case where, unless you knew and understood exactly what the script at `${url}` does, this didn't lead to somehow surprising results.

That's the case here, too, assuming it's the umbrel.sh script that does this to your machine (and it wasn't you doing something else); it's just a script that downloads more stuff opaquely from the internet. It seems as if this script misdetected your Ubuntu as debian, and mostly just broke it. Because umbrel.com contains **no** documentation whatsoever on how to install without the malfunctioning script, we can't even advise on how to do it correctly. (In exchange we get a lot of annoying animations that keep us from reading what is relevant, and a lot of "humblebrag" marketing speech.)

In other words: this is not something you'll want to install on your machine. It seems it's meant to work on environments that the vendor has under full control. This kind of installation script without proper packaging for the few target OSes it supports is a classical indicator of this "works on my machine"-ware. (By the way, that's *also* not a predictor of high reliability *on* the commercial hardware they sell – being able to properly package your software for an operating system is kind of the starting point for this kind of embedded development.)

What you *can* do is try to set up a VM with debian inside, it seems this is supposed to run well on debian – but what they put into your `/etc/apt/sources*` is already a repository for an obsolete version of debian, so, I'm not even sure I could recommend that.

Maybe just use something else.

Comment: by the way, not saying this isn't cool software – I simply don't know – but the fact how its sole way of installing seems to be an undocumented script you're supposed to directly pipe into your shell is a big red flag.

Comment: (I do think the whole bitcoin/ligtning/general cryptocurrency focus on the website *is* a red flag, because it's 2023, and there's basically mostly fraudsters and victims in that sphere by now, but you do you.)